# Can I get notified of data availability on network connection?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, operating-system

I want to read from connection available data, but don't get blocked. Neither I would like to periodically check for new data.

If there is no data available yet, but program expects data from socket, then:

1. tell OS that program is expecting data on this socket
2. do something else from task queue
3. OS will execute callback/function that will let know program internals that data are available (ie. put reading task to some queue)

I know, that are many patterns involving multiple threads, workers, queues, data availability checking, etc... But, I'm thinking about that program gets notified of new data availability, ie. *Tell, don't ask* principle.

Comment: depends on the OS. For linux there's a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2540974/4178025

Comment: 'program gets notified of new data availability' - yeah, that's what happens when a thread blocks on input, either in a dedicated manner, waiting for just network data, or on some 'shared' input queue where other data can also arrive - it has execution removed from it until data is available.

Comment: You will need something based on select on a separate thread and then set an event or something like that.

Comment: @Diego I didn't quite understood the accepted answer. However, one of answers mentioned http://linux.die.net/man/2/select in it, which looks suitable - O(1) threads count for any number of files/sockets. It's not that hard, but I didn't know what am I really looking for, and where to begin search :)

Comment: Thanks for help. If anyone wants to put it into answer, I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: @Miro the accepted answer is about getting signals when data is available in file descriptors set to asynchronous mode. But to be honest, now that I think it twice, I would avoid that; signal handlers are quite restricted in what they [can safely do](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-26/index.html) and things can go wrong easily I guess.